# Why is this dictionary-updating code slow? How can it I improve it's efficiency?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to reduce the processor time consumed by a python application, and after profiling it, I've found a small chunk of code consuming more processor time than it should:

```
class Stats(DumpableObject):
    members_offsets = [
        ('blkio_delay_total', 40),
        ('swapin_delay_total', 56),
        ('read_bytes', 248),
        ('write_bytes', 256),
        ('cancelled_write_bytes', 264)
    ]

[...other code here...]

    def accumulate(self, other_stats, destination, coeff=1):
        """Update destination from operator(self, other_stats)"""
        dd = destination.__dict__
        sd = self.__dict__
        od = other_stats.__dict__
        for member, offset in Stats.members_offsets:
            dd[member] = sd[member] + coeff * od[member]
```

Why is this so expensive? How can I improve the efficiency of this code?

### Context:

One of my favourite Linux tools, [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/), uses far more processor time than I think is appropriate for a monitoring tool - quickly consuming minutes of processor time; using the built in --profile option, total function calls approached 4 million running for only 20 seconds. I've observed similar behaviour on other systems, across reboots, & on multiple kernels. pycallgraph highlighted `accumulate` as one of a few time-consuming functions.

After studying the code for a full week, I think that dictionaries are the best choice for a data structure here, as a large number of threads to update will require many lookups, but don't understand why this code is expensive. Extensive search failed to enlighten. I don't understand the `curses`, `socket`, and `struct` libraries well enough to ask a self-contained question. I'm not asking for code as lightweight as pure C is in i7z.

I'd post images & other data, but I don't have the reputation.

The iotop git repository: http://repo.or.cz/w/iotop.git/tree (The code in question is in data.py, beginning line 73)

The system in question runs Ubuntu 13.04 on an Intel E6420 with 2GB of ram. Kernel 3.8.0-35-generic.

*(I wish that Guillaume Chazarain had written more docstrings!)*

Comment: That code looks reasonably trim to me.  You're not using `offsets` at all, so perhaps a `dict` might be a better choice for `Stats.member_offsets` (you could avoid the cost of tuple unpacking).  But that should be a pretty minor optimization.  Honestly, your question is a bit all over the place -- `curses`, `socket`, `struct`?  what do those have to do with the problem at hand?  How do you know that this is slower than it *should* be?

Comment: Are you sure it is expensive, or is it just getting called a lot?

Comment: Agree with @BrenBarn. It really doesn't look that expensive to me.